# Use sikuli-script jar without ide .Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, dll, sikuli

I'm trying to use sikuli-script.jar without using sikuli-ide.
It dint even execute the following lines

```
     Screen x=new Screen();
     x.click("File");
```

but it keeps on throwing can't find dependent libraries exception
But all the dependent dlls are present there.

I even set path to the lib folder manually using

```
 System.setProperty("java.library.tmpdir",   "D:/Madhan/branches/Branch_DVI/GUI/Spritz/test/libs");
```

But it is not working .I have searched in every possible way in launchpad.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
 File "D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py", line 22, in <module>

  m java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\test\libs\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at sikuli.Sikuli$py.f$0(D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py:211)
    at sikuli.Sikuli$py.call_function(D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py)
    at sikuli$py.f$0(D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\__init__.py:3)
   at sikuli$py.call_function(D:\Madhan\branches\Branch_DVI\GUI\Spritz\lib\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\sikuli\__init__.py)
   at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(<string>:1)
   at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(<string>)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to comment as I don't have sufficient reputation. That's why I'm 'answering'. I'm also fairly new to SikuliX.
The latest versions of SikuliX on installation don't create sikuli-script.jar in them. They just have a sikuli-ide.jar or sikulixapi.jar.

Try https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.0.1

Create a folder, say 'SikuliX' in your local drive.
On installing, this will give a fat jar file. The 'SikuliX' folder will also have the libs.
You need to add this libs location to your path (C:\SikuliX\libs)

Answer (score 0):

please try to refer to http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

I don't know which version you used. 
In 1.0.1 version, D:/Madhan/branches/Branch_DVI/GUI/Spritz/test/libs should be created when you first import sikuli-script.jar and add this libs path into your system PATH automatically, so you don't need to add it to java.library.tmpdir. try to Include sikuli-script.jar in the CLASSPATH of your Java project and import org.sikuli.script.* in your java source code.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the given steps to use sikuli without IDE:**

1. In your java program 1st import required sikuli libraries ( import org.sikuli.script.*;
   )
2. add sikuli-script.jar or sikuli-java.jar into your build path of your java project.
3. Update your Environment variables  sikuli libraries path.
4. export your jar (executable).
5. Run this cmd

   ```
   cd "your directory"

   "java -jar your_program.jar"
   ```

Comment: There is no need for export it is as jar[No need for 4 and 5].It's an optional one, and `sikuli-java.jar` is the one that comes with latest sikuli.

Comment: If you want to execute your program via command line then you can use 4 and 5.